# Quick get all variables from $_POST, how to handle undefined if all fields are required?

Tags: php, forms, post, undefined

I've a form where all fields are required so I thought of doing something like this to retrieve all variables from `$_POST`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;
```

Then I validate the data and use the variables where needed.

Is there a quick way to tell if at least one variable is undefined without having to go `isset` on each and every one of them?

My first idea was to count how many fields I have and compare with `count`:

```
if (count($_POST) == 10)
```

But this is not dynamic, I have to change that number when I add new fields.

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: if you pass number of fields in a hidden input, you can make it dynamic on server side using `count`

Comment: That doesn't seem very dynamic... I still have to edit that number when I add new fields.

Comment: I don't see other way. You can make js function which counts number of fields and adds a hidden input on submit. But in case client has disabled js, you're in problem

Comment: It's probably a better idea to do the validation client side as well...

Comment: You do realize that your code is basically emulating `register_globals`, right? I would create a "form model" class to represent the form, with properties for needed fields, then iterate over its properties with `get_class_vars`, `get_object_vars` or similar to pull in only the values you need rather than all of them. (And don't listen to advice about omitting server side validation, that's just wrong.)

Comment: Come to think of it, `count` won't work, because `$_POST` will anyway be populated will all your inputs, just some of them won't have values. Unless you call `array_filter` first. Jon's solution is good :)

Comment: @DCoder: It's just an example. On my actual code I've an array with all the field names that I use to build the form, so I'm finding out if `$key` is there before I do `$$key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a quick and easy way to do it you can do:

```
if(in_array("", $_POST)) {
    //a field is empty
}
```

Comment: Yes! How didn't I think of this?. Thanks, it works for my purposes.